# How to remove app from wishlist?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-wishlist

How can I remove an app from wishlist? I clicked the add to wishlist button by mistake..
I'm looking for this but i can't find, is there a way?

I tried to unistall  the app, search in the app page and others places like the wishlist itself.

Comment: Wait, what? Haw long has a wish list been there?

Comment: Since october 17th apparently.. check out [this](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/17/play-store-wishlists-are-rolling-out-right-now/), wishlist wasn't the only thing in the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i couldn't resolve my problem but after contacting Google's support here some potencial answers for some users.

**Clean Google Play and Download Manager Cache**

For Google Play:

1. Visit `Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage applications`
2. Tab over to "All"
3. Select the Play Store app, and then tap "Clear cache" and "Clear data"

For the Download manager:

1. Visit `Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage applications`
2. Tab over to "All"
3. Select "Download manager," and then tap "Clear data" and "Clear cache"

**Uninstall updates from Google play**

1. Go to "Home" > "Menu" > "Settings" > "Applications" > "Manage applications"
2. Touch the "All" tab
3. Scroll down and select the Play Store app
4. Touch "Uninstall updates"

This will revert Google Play to the original version that came with your device. Google Play should automatically self-update to the current version within a few days - there's no way to permanently uninstall updates. However, you can perform the following steps to ensure the latest version of Google Play is updated properly:

1. Launch Google Play
2. Switch to the Home screen
3. Wait 5-10 minutes for the app to self-update
4. Re-launch the Google Play Store app

After that the support couldn't help me anymore..

I believe my problem is a bug, so maybe in future versions it'll be fixed, anyway when I accomplish this, I'll post here.

**EDIT:**
Google Play Store updated to 3.10.9 and now each wishlist item has like a remove icon besides it, so you click there and it's removed! Nice and easy.

Comment: On play.google.com, the button is missing for a non-available item.

Answer (score 4):

If you go into the play store item that you added to your wishlist and click the same icon that you used to add it to the wishlist it should remove it.

Comment: But the button is now the share button, there's no more that flag

Comment: @Markissimo The method is same. Play Store has issues regarding this. Contact Google.

Comment: This method worked for me.  I did have to reopen the wishlist, but not play store, for the item to be gone.

Comment: The button is missing for a non-available item.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried many things (clearing Play data, clearing cache, uninstall, force stop restarting the device) and finally found a solution:

Use Google Chrome and open two tabs.

1. In the first tab open the new Apps and click **Add to Wishlist**
2. In the second tab open the app that cannot be removed from the wishlist
3. Right click at second tab then click **Inspect element**
4. In **Elements** right click and click **Edit attribute** at **data-docid** and **data-server-cookie**, copy the value in **Notepad**
   An example **data-docid** is com.noodlecake.blockheads and **data-server-cookie** is CAIaIwohEh8KGWNvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
5. Goto 1st page right click at button **Added to Wishlist** and click **Inspect element**
6. In 1st page **Elements**, use **Edit attribute** replace all the **data-docid** and **data-server-cookie** values with the 2nd page **data-docid** and **data-server-cookie** values
7. Now you can click **Remove** wishlist on the first Chrome tab.

Comment: This worked for me. I had purchased an app but it was still in my wishlist. I couldn't remove it via the Play Store app or website as i didn't see the remove button. Following the steps in this answer allowed me to delete it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Google play. Search for the application you're trying to remove. When the page loads, you should see a ribbon-shaped icon in the upper right-hand corner. There should be a check mark. Click it. The icon should change into a plus ("+") symbol. Check the wishlist. The item should be gone.

Comment: On play.google.com, the button is missing for a non-available item.